# Вывод в jEditorPane содержимого xml файла без тег

Tags: xml, java

Здравствуйте, я недавно начала изучать java и столкнулась с проблемой. Мне необходимо вывести в jEditorPane содержимое книги, книга является файлом xml. Я использую:

```
jEditorPane1.setEditorKit(new XMLEditorKit());
try{    
            jEditorPane1.read(new FileInputStream(library.Fil.filename.get_value()), new FileInputStream(library.Fil.filename.get_value()));

}catch (IOException e) {};
```

Выводится отформатированный раскрашенный текст с тегами, но мне нужно только текстовое содержание книги. Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким способом это можно реализовать

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю использовать XML-парсеры, лучше всего (имхо) подойдёт SAX